# How to check if date equals date of datetime property only using query parameters

Tags: date, datetime, odata, odata-v4

I have a `DateTime` property.

I want to check if a date is equal to the date in my property and it has to be done purely in the url query parameters available in OData v4.

This doesn't work :(

```
GET ~/odata/foo$filter=date(myProperty) eq date(1980-01-01)
```

Yes I can use `greater then or equal` but that's is already working as intended. It's `equal` and `not equal` that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ABNF](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt) rules, Date value is a value with format:

> dateValue = year "-" month "-" day

So, I think you shouldn't add `date` prefix. That's:

> GET ~/odata/foo$filter=date(myProperty) eq 1980-01-01

Here's some test cases provided by ODataTeam:

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/test/E2ETest/WebStack.QA.Test.OData/DateAndTimeOfDay/DateAndTimeOfDayTest.cs#L169-L171

and
https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/test/E2ETest/WebStack.QA.Test.OData/DateAndTimeOfDay/DateAndTimeOfDayTest.cs#L208-L212

Besides, there's a simple tutorial you can refer to:

http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-04-date-and-timeofday-support

Thanks. Hope it can help.